# Using forms and templates and _submit callback

Tags: 6, forms

I'm trying to wrap my head around the process of creating a form and handling the submitted data using `x_submit()`.

I start by having a form callback:

```
function world_form(&$form_state) {

  // if ($form_state['post']) { drupal_set_message("Solved!"); }

  $forms['fieldset_options'] =
    array('#type' => 'fieldset',
          '#title' => t('Options'),
          '#collapsible' => FALSE,
          '#collapsed' => FALSE);

  $forms['fieldset_options']['tags'] =
    array('#type' => 'item', '#title' => 'Simple stuff');

  $forms['fieldset_options']['checkbox1'] =
    array('#type' => 'checkbox', '#title' => t('Solve world problems'));

  $forms['fieldset_options']['submit'] =
    array('#type' => 'button', '#button_type' => 'submit', '#value' => 'Go!');

  // $forms['submit'] = array('#type' => 'submit', '#value' => 'Go!');

  return $forms;
}
```

So I specify a theme callback, which takes me to a file `world.tpl.php` in which I do:

```
print drupal_get_form('world_form');
```

which invokes my form callback. So far so good. Now the problem I have is that I want to handle when this form is submitted (more specifically, I want the value of the checkbox when it is checked). I read a lot of documentation and most mention the `world_form_submit` function. So I create one like this:

```
function world_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message("Posted!");
}
```

But after I've done that the function isn't called. However if I instead use the line which is commented out in my form function and comment out the `'#type' => 'button'` field it DOES get called and I can now access the checkbox state, however the problem I have now is that the form is not updated with the state of the checkbox (I.e. if I check the box and submit I get to the same page but the box is no longer checked).

So my questions are:

1. Why isn't the `_submit` callback called when I use a "regular" submit button? Do I have to use the `$forms['submit']` way?
2. If I do get the `_submit` callback called, can I still update my form to reflect what it was before I submitted, and
3. How can I get the checkbox state in my `world.tpl.php` file? Say I want to print something if it is checked.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Many questions here:

- Your form function function should return the form array and doesn't need an argument unless you need it for something specific.
- You should at least have an element of type 'submit' (not button) in your form.
- Chances are good your submit function will get called if you implement it this way.
- If the form fails validation, FAPI will restore it to the values submitted, keeping what was typed by the user.
- You shoudn't try to embed business logic in your template, but rather in your module and/or a preprocess function.

---

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the return statement in the example. I added it now. It is there. But the problem for me now is still that I want to do something with my checkbox values... assuming I do something in my `_submit` function, how would I return the result to the template file? E.g. I fetch data from a db in the `_submit` function, where do I store that data to have it printed out in the template?

Comment: Ideally, with a [theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/6) function. [This document](http://drupal.org/files/theme_flow_6_1.pdf) may be of help.